# how to write a loop of the number of for loops in R?

Tags: r, loops

this is probably a simple one, but I somehow got stuck...

I need to many loops to get the result of every sample in my support like the usual stacked loops:

```
for (a in 1:N1){
 for (b in 1:N2){
  for (c in 1:N3){
   ...
   }
  }
}
```

but the number of the for loops needed in this messy system depends on another random variable, let's say,
    for(f in 1:N.for)

so how can I write a for loop to do deal with this? Or are there more elegant ways to do this?

note that the difference is that the nested for loops above (the variables a,b,c,...) do matter in my calculations, but the variable f of the for loop that controls for the number of for loops needed does not go into any of my calculations for my real purpose - all it does is count/ensure the number of for loops needed is correct.

Did I make it clear?

---

So what I am actually trying to do is generate all the possible combinations of a number of peoples preferences towards others.

Let's say I have 6 people (the simplest case for my purpose): Abi, Bob, Cath, Dan, Eva, Fay.

Abi and Bob have preference lists of C D E F ( 4!=24 possible permutations for each of them);

Cath and Dan have preference lists of A B and E F, respectively (2! * 2! = 4 possible permutations for each of them);

Eva and Fay have preference lists of A B C D (4!=24 possible permutations for each of them);

So all together there should be 24*24*4*4*24*24 possible permutations of preferences when taking all six them together.

I am just wondering what is a clear, easy and systematic way to generate them all at once?

I'd want them in the format such as

```
c.prefs <- as.matrix(data.frame(Abi = c("Eva", "Fay", "Dan", "Cath"),Bob = c("Dan", "Eva", "Fay", "Cath"))
```

but any clear format is fine...

Thank you so much!!

Comment: It would be better to explain what you're *actually* trying to do.  Nobody sets out to just use an undefined number of loops.  There is a reason you think this is the route you need to go - tell us what you're actually trying to do and I'm sure we can come up with something a lot better than this.

Comment: Thank you Dason! You are absolutely right! I will update this with my actual task!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you have a list of each loop variable and its maximum value, ordered from the outermost to innermost variable.

```
loops <- list(a=2, b=3, c=2)
```

You could create a data frame with all the loop variable values in the correct order with:

```
(indices <- rev(do.call(expand.grid, lapply(rev(loops), seq_len))))
#    a b c
# 1  1 1 1
# 2  1 1 2
# 3  1 2 1
# 4  1 2 2
# 5  1 3 1
# 6  1 3 2
# 7  2 1 1
# 8  2 1 2
# 9  2 2 1
# 10 2 2 2
# 11 2 3 1
# 12 2 3 2
```

If the code run at the innermost point of the nested loop doesn't depend on the previous iterations, you could use something like `apply` to process each iteration independently. Otherwise you could loop through the rows of the data frame with a single loop:

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(indices))) {
  # You can get "a" with indices$a[i], "b" with indices$b[i], etc.
}
```

Comment: I think `expand.grid` alone might be the answer. `prefs <- data.frame(Abi = c("Eva", "Fay", "Dan", "Cath"),Bob = c("Dan", "Eva", "Fay", "Cath")); prefs_combinations <- do.call(expand.grid, prefs)`

Comment: @ssdecontrol the problem with `expand.grid` alone (without the two calls to `rev`) is that it treats the last element of `prefs` at the outermost loop variable and it treats the first element of `prefs` as the innermost loop variable. If OP doesn't care about loop order then no need for this.

Comment: Okay, I think I misunderstood the question. It's still unclear to me.

Comment: @ssdecontrol thanks for your suggestion! prefs_combinations did not seem to return what I need... but it's probably because I didn't make it clear enough. Thanks still!!

Comment: @Meredithu I'm planning to graduate in 2 months and then start a postdoc/lecturer position at MIT Sloan. I'd love to chat more, but folks tend to get testy about non-Stack Overflow conversations in the comments. Can we move this to email? I'm josilber@mit.edu.

Answer (score 0):

For the way of doing the calculation, an option is to use the Reduce function or some other higher-order function.

Since your data is not inherently ordered (an individual is part of a set, its preferences are part of the set) I would keep indivudals in a factor and have eg preferences in lists named with the individuals. If you have large data you can store it in an environment.

The first code is just how to make it reproducible. the problem domain was akin for graph oriented naming. You just need to change in the first line and in runif to change the behavior.

```
    #people
    verts <- factor(c(LETTERS[1:10]))

    #relations, disallow preferring yourself
    edges<-lapply(seq_along(verts), function(ind) {
      levels(verts)[-ind]
    })
    names(edges) <- levels(verts)

    #directions
    #say you have these stored in a list or something
    pool <- levels(verts)
    directions<-lapply(pool, function(vert) {
      relations <- pool[unique(round(runif(5, 1, 10)))]
      relations[!(vert %in%  relations)]
    })
    names(directions) = pool

    num_prefs <- (lapply(directions, length))
    names(num_prefs) <- names(directions)

    #First take factorial of each persons preferences, 
    #then reduce that with multiplication
    combinations <-
    Reduce(`*`, 
           sapply(num_prefs, factorial)
    )
```

I hope this answers your question!